# Why does XSLT processor produce an empty file when the input XML matches nothing?

Tags: xslt-2.0, saxon

I am using XSLT 2.0 (with SaxonHE) to transform some XML Schema Documents into a set of text files.
Let say I want a different output file for each xs:complexType found in the input XSD, my template will lool like the following

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <xsl:output method="text" />
 

 <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*" />
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="xs:complexType[@name]">
  <xsl:variable name="fileName" select="concat('target/',@name,'.txt')" />
  <xsl:result-document href="{$fileName}"><xsl:value-of select="$fileName"/></xsl:result-document>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

For any XSD containing at least one element of the xs:complexType, the output I got is correctly produced in the 'target/{$fileName}.txt' and no other file is produced in the process.

My question arises when I run this transformation with a XSD that does not contain any xs:complexType, the processor produces a default, empty xml file whose name is follow ${input_file}.xml where ${input_file} is the name of the input file. (for instance books.xsd is transformed into books.xsd.xml).
How to get rid of that default xml file when nothing matches the templates selected by my transformation ?

The processor I use is SaxonHE9, but I got the same result with others.

Comment: So how exactly do you run Saxon, from the command line (how does the command line exactly look), with Java or .NET (how does you Java or .NET code look), with an editor like oXygen?

Comment: In general, https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#executing-a-transformation mandates "An implicit result tree is also created when the result sequence is empty, provided that no xsl:result-document instruction has been evaluated during the course of the transformation. In this situation the implicit result tree will consist of a document node with no children." so this could be the reason for a final result when you don't want one, although the details you have provided so far don't explain why you would get a certain file name you say you get.

Comment: The saxon processor (Java implementation) is invoked in the command line as follows : 
java -classpath saxon9he.jar net.sf.saxon.Transform -t -xsl:transform.xsl
-s:./schemas
-o:./target

where both ./schemas and ./target are directories since I want the processor to run on several input files at once.

Comment: You might want to add a tag for Saxon to get help whether it is possible to process a directory of input files with the `-s` option without generating a result file for those input files that don't produce any secondary result files using `xsl:result-document`.

Comment: so I have just added a tag for saxon to get help. please Mr Michael Kay, help me on that issue ...

Answer (score 1):

Martin has identified the reason: in effect the XSLT 2.0 spec mandates that there is at least one result document, so if no secondary result documents are created then the primary result is created, even if it's empty. It's a horribly convoluted rule but I think some WG members felt it was needed for XSLT 1.0 compatibility.

The primary result has a file name determined by the "base output URI". When you process a whole directory from the command line, then the base output URI for each transformation is formed from the name of the output directory and the final part of the name of the input file.

The XSLT 3.0 spec relaxes this rule. It says (non-normatively):

> In previous versions of this specification it was stated that when the
>   raw result of the initial template or function is an empty sequence, a
>   result tree should be produced if and only if the transformation
>   generates no secondary results (that is, if it does not invoke
>   xsl:result-document). This provision is most likely to have a
>   noticeable effect if the transformation produces serialized results,
>   and these results are written to persistent storage: the effect is
>   then that a transformation producing an empty principal result will
>   overwrite any existing content at the base output URI location if and
>   only if the transformation produces no other output. Processor APIs
>   offering backwards compatibility with earlier versions of XSLT must
>   respect this behavior, but there is no requirement for new processor
>   APIs to do so.

Saxon has taken the cautious approach of retaining the 2.0 behaviour for the time being, but it's certainly something worth looking at again.